# Shortest Remaining Time First Query

Tags: operating-system, scheduling

If they are two processes with the following Data, How should the Gantt Chart be?(SRTF scheduling)

Process    Arrival   Burst
P1            0        17
P2            1        16

So will the process P1 be completed first and then P2 will start executing..or P1 will have to wait for 16 milli seconds?

Answer (score 0):

I feel the conflict can be resolved either by choosing the process which came earlier or by the process which has the longest burst. In this case, on choosing either of the approaches, P1 will be completed first.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot..
I do understand that P1 comes first but why will the processor select the process with the longest burst?

Answer (score 0):

It's going to choose P1 because at the time P2 didn't exist

P1 AT =0 thus will start first

next step they will be equal but as the processor is working already on p1 it will prefer to keep working on it until interruption or termination

Answer (score 0):

In this case it gets P2 at 1, then it checks for remaining time. As both remaining times are same, it put new process; P2 in the queue for next execution(after P1's completion).